# Can't save/create files using Store.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, save, electron, store

So I wanted to save a file on the client storage using Store.js.

I can change the date using `store.set` and i can `log` it to console to see the change, but then it's supposed to be saved in app data where it's not created.

I tried to get the Path where it's being saved and it's :

`C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\stoma2/Categories.json`

I noticed that there is a "/" so I tried :

`C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\stoma2\Categories.json`
and :
`C:/Users/USER/AppData/Roaming/stoma2/Categories.json`

But all 3 of them didn't work.

This is my Store.js :

```
 const fs = require('browserify-fs');
 var fs2 = require('filereader'),Fs2 = new fs2();
 const electron = window.require('electron');
 const path = require('path');


 class Store {
     constructor(opts) {
       // Renderer process has to get `app` module via `remote`, whereas the main process can get it directly
       // app.getPath('userData') will return a string of the user's app data directory path.
       //const userDataPath = (electron.app || electron.remote.app).getPath('userData');
       var userDataPath = (electron.app || electron.remote.app).getPath('userData');
       for(var i=0;i<userDataPath.length;i++){
         if(userDataPath.charAt(i)=="\\"){
           userDataPath = userDataPath.replace("\\","/");
         }
       }


       // We'll use the `configName` property to set the file name and path.join to bring it all together as a string
       this.path = path.join(userDataPath, opts.configName + '.json');

       this.data = parseDataFile(this.path, opts.defaults);
       console.log(this.path);
     }

   // This will just return the property on the `data` object
   get(key) {
     return this.data[key];
   }

   // ...and this will set it
   set(key, val) {
     this.data[key] = val;
     // Wait, I thought using the node.js' synchronous APIs was bad form?
     // We're not writing a server so there's not nearly the same IO demand on the process
     // Also if we used an async API and our app was quit before the asynchronous write had a chance to complete,
     // we might lose that data. Note that in a real app, we would try/catch this.
     fs.writeFile(this.path, JSON.stringify(this.data));
   }
 }

 function parseDataFile(filePath, data) {
   // We'll try/catch it in case the file doesn't exist yet, which will be the case on the first application run.
   // `fs.readFileSync` will return a JSON string which we then parse into a Javascript object
   try {
     return JSON.parse(Fs2.readAsDataURL(new File(filePath)));
   } catch(error) {
     // if there was some kind of error, return the passed in defaults instead.
     return data;
   }
 }

 // expose the class
 export default Store;
```

There might be a probleme fith js.writeFile() (well that's the source of probleme).

and this is my call :

```
 //creation
 const storeDefCat = new Store({
   configName: "Categories",
   defaults: require("../data/DefaultCategorie.json")
 })
 //call for the save
 storeDefCat.set('Pizza',{id:0,path:storeDefCat.get('Pizza').path});
```

For now if possible,I might need to find another way to save the file.

And i tried : fs : It doesn't work for me for some reason (I get strange errors that they don't want to be fixed..) .

If anyone has an Idea then please I would be grateful.

Comment: You are cutting and pasting code without understanding it. Read through that tutorial link I posted yesterday again.

Comment: It's not am not understanding it, When I tried it with normal fs api I get Strange errors abouts functions not existinf, so I used `browserify-fs` to counter the errors but that doesn't seem to solve the probleme. (TypeError: fs.writeFileSync is not a function)

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to fix the probleme, Why fs was sending me errors about undefined functions?Why file wasn't getting created ? It has **NOTHING** to do with the code it self, but the imports...

To clearify, I was using :

`const fs = require('fs');`

And the solution is to make it like :

`const fs = window.require('fs');`

Just adding `window.` fixed all the problems .Since it's my first time using electron I wasn't used to import from the `window` but it seems it's necessary.And more over...There was no posts saying this is the fix.